# MFC application not supporting wide monitors

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC application that works fine when the monitor resolution is 1280 x 1024.

If I change the monitor resolution to 1920 x 1200, the application window will not fit the complete monitor. So I want to know what changes I need to do in my code so that it fits to any resolution monitor.

Comment: So if you maximize the window it doesn't fit the whole monitor?? Can you post an image on http://imgur.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

There's a good chance that your MFC app is limiting the size of it's window.

I'd look at handlers for

- WM_GETMINMAXINFO (the most likely culprit)

  > Sent to a window when the size or position of the window is about to change. An application can use this message to override the window's default maximized size and position, or its default minimum or maximum tracking size

  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626(v=vs.85).aspx
- WM_SIZE 
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632646(v=vs.85).aspx
- WM_SIZING 
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632647(v=vs.85).aspx
- WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED 
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632652(v=vs.85).aspx
- WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING 
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653(v=vs.85).aspx